# iOS UITextView Not Properly Handling Phone Number in Field

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My app simply displays a phone number in a UITextView. I have made sure that the text view is enabled to detect phone numbers. And, indeed, when the user long presses on it, it will give the option to call or Send Message. If I click either one of these, the app simply crashes. As there is no code to handle anything and is just relying on built-in functionality, I get no error messages when the app crashes. The only thing remotely close I get is this:

> Updating selectors after delegate removal failed with: Error
> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service with
> pid 99 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated
> from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to
> service with pid 99 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was
> invalidated from this process.}

"Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question."

Desired behavior is after I click the checkmark in inspector for it to detect phone numbers, a user can long press the number, choose send message, and have it open messages. The specific problem is this crashes it. The shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem is to add a Textview, click it, and in inspector, tel it to detect phone numbers. There, does that help others answer the question?

```
 cell.text = @"555-867-5309";
```

[image]

Comment: There’s not enough here for us to reproduce the problem. I use `UITextView` with `dataDetectors` set to `.all` and it detects/calls phone numbers fine. Perhaps you can try doing this in a blank app and see if you can reproduce the problem there. Slowly add stuff to your new, blank project until you are able to reproduce the crash. And perhaps share details about the physical phone on which you are testing this (iOS version, model, etc.). But at this point, you do not appear to have shared any more information than you have in your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77553442/1271826).

Comment: @Rob the problem isn’t that it doesn’t detect. It detects them fine. The system menu that gives options to call or send message pops up fine as well. The problem is that the whole thing crashes with no error given in console at all for why it crashed when selecting send message.

Comment: Yes, I understand that is your problem. But it works fine for us. We can make calls or send the messages via the text view data detector. So we need more details about your configuration and/or show us the precise steps where we can reproduce your crash on our devices. It is hard to help you if we cannot reproduce it (or at least understand how your configuration differs from ours). Please edit the question to include more info. E.g., physical iPhone or simulator? What Xcode version? What macOS version? What iOS version? Etc.

Comment: @Rob Xcode 15.0.1, macOS 14.1.1, iOS 17, minimum deployment iOS 15.

Comment: @Rob added code and image, happens on physical device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256071/discussion-between-rob-and-user717452).